# mongoose: how to get string representation of query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I implementing module who automatically generate mongoose query by requested params, so for simplified test process I need to be able to get text representation of final query. How could I do that?

Like we have something like this:

`var q = AppModel.find({id:777}).sort({date:-1})`

I need to get something like this

```
"db.appmodels.where({id:777}).sort({date: -1})"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set debug for mongoose, which would by default send the queries to console, to use the following:

```
mongoose.set('debug', function (collectionName, method, query, doc) {
 // Here query is what you are looking for.
 // so whatever you want to do with the query
 // would be done in here
})
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the whole query.

Answer (score 2):

Given a query object `q` you can rebuild the query using its fields, namely `q._conditions` and `q._update`. This is undocumented though and could easily break between versions of Mongoose (tested on Mongoose 4.0.4).